# Android canvas ignoring fontsize

Tags: android, canvas, android-fonts

No matter if I choose setTextSize(30), 300, or use the getResources, the text always appears very tiny on my screen.

Why isn't the text scaling?

```
private void drawScore(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setARGB(1, 51, 42, 53);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        int scaledSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.font);
        p.setTextSize(scaledSize);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(scorer.points() + "pts"), canvas.getClipBounds().centerX(), 50, paint);
    }

<resources>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font">300sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: You're setting the text size there on `p`, but you're passing `paint` in the `drawText()` call. Did you get them mixed up?

Comment: !! Yes, thanks @MikeM. So I tried using p, and lowered the size to "40sp" in the dimens file but I see nothing.. is there code I'm missing from using "p"?

Comment: `p.setARGB(1, 51, 42, 53)` - You've set the alpha there to almost completely transparent - `1`. All of those parameters take values in the range 0-255.